# How do I use Excel VBA to copy a worksheet from a workbook selected using a file browser?

Tags: vba, excel, file-browser

I'm trying to create what I thought should be a really simple Macro.  I deal with the same report every day, which is updated each morning.  That said, it would be really nice for me to be able to have the data I worked with yesterday in the same workbook as the new data from a given morning.

Basically, all I want to do is copy a worksheet from a different workbook (the one with yesterday's report) into my active workbook (the one with today's report) using a file browser.

The Application.GetOpenFilename method opens up a file browser like what I want, but I can't figure out how to use the directory string that it returns to copy in the worksheet I want.

Here's the code I've been using:

```
Sub Macro5()

Dim todayWBName As String
Dim yesterdayWB As Workbook
Set todayWB = ActiveWorkbook
todayWBName = todayWB.Name

'open file from last business day
    yesterdayWBName = Application.GetOpenFilename( _
                      Title:="Select backorder file from last business day", _
                      MultiSelect:=False)
    If yesterdayWBName = False Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
        End If
    Workbooks.Open yesterdayWBName
    Set yesterdayWB = ActiveWorkbook
    todayWB.Activate

'copy in yesterday's info
    yesterdayWB(1).Copy After:=todayWB.Sheets(1)
    yesterdayWB.Close
    Sheets("Sheet 1 (2)").Name = "YesterdayResolution"
    Sheets(1).Activate

End Sub
```

If anyone could tell me what I'm doing wrong here, I'd really appreciate it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. Use the string result from the `GetOpenFileName` and pass it directly to the `Workbooks.Open` method, handling the return value as an object (workbook) which assigns to `yesterdayWB` object.

Also, you have an error:

```
yesterdayWB(1).Copy After:=todayWB.Sheets(1)
```

The workbook object is not subscriptable, what you meant (I think) was `yesterdayWB.Worksheets(1).Copy ...`

```
Sub Macro5()

    Dim yesterdayWB As Workbook
    Dim yesterdayWBName As String
    Dim todayWB As Workbook

    Set todayWB = ActiveWorkbook

    'open file from last business day
    yesterdayWBName = Application.GetOpenFilename( _
                      Title:="Select backorder file from last business day", _
                      MultiSelect:=False)
    If yesterdayWBName = False Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Set yesterdayWB = Workbooks.Open(yesterdayWBName)

    'copy in yesterday's info
    yesterdayWB.Worksheets(1).Copy After:=todayWB.Sheets(1)
    yesterdayWB.Close
    ' the sheet you copied is at index "2" because you put it after Sheets(1)
    todayWB.Sheets(2).Name = "YesterdayResolution"
    todayWB.Sheets(1).Activate

End Sub
```